# sharepoint foundation 2013 workflow - how to collect the approval from list of approvers from a group

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I need to create a workflow where in I need to collect approvals from list of approvers in a group in a sequentail manner as a sub task in the overall workflow.

if any one person wont approve then then that "pre-appovers" task becomes invalid resulting in disagreed state of the workflow.

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Free Edition

Please help with a relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way of developing and overcoming the limitations of free sharepoint edition is to create forms via layout pages and leverage SharePoint object model for all the workflow scenarios.